# InvalidArgumentError : You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1/X' with dtype float

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn

I am new to tensorflow and tflearn and getting this error while training the model.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1/X' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_1/X = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Here is my code for preference.

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
Y = np.array([i[1] for i in train])

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
test_y = np.array([i[1] for i in test])
```

where train and test are numpy arrays having first element as image and second element as label. I am trying to fit my model by this line.

```
model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=5, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

This is the complete error that I am getting:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-cf830d06009d> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=5, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.pyc in fit(self, X_inputs, Y_targets, n_epoch, validation_set, show_metric, batch_size, shuffle, snapshot_epoch, snapshot_step, excl_trainops, validation_batch_size, run_id, callbacks)
    213                          excl_trainops=excl_trainops,
    214                          run_id=run_id,
--> 215                          callbacks=callbacks)
    216 
    217     def predict(self, X):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.pyc in fit(self, feed_dicts, n_epoch, val_feed_dicts, show_metric, snapshot_step, snapshot_epoch, shuffle_all, dprep_dict, daug_dict, excl_trainops, run_id, callbacks)
    331                                                        (bool(self.best_checkpoint_path) | snapshot_epoch),
    332                                                        snapshot_step,
--> 333                                                        show_metric)
    334 
    335                             # Update training state

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.pyc in _train(self, training_step, snapshot_epoch, snapshot_step, show_metric)
    772         tflearn.is_training(True, session=self.session)
    773         _, train_summ_str = self.session.run([self.train, self.summ_op],
--> 774                                              feed_batch)
    775 
    776         # Retrieve loss value from summary string

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1/X' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_1/X = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'input_1/X', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/kernelapp.py", line 469, in main
    app.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/kernelapp.py", line 459, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 162, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/ipkernel.py", line 281, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/ipkernel.py", line 245, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/ipkernel.py", line 389, in execute_request
    shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2741, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-fe1453e052a7>", line 6, in <module>
    convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/layers/core.py", line 81, in input_data
    placeholder = tf.placeholder(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name="X")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1/X' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_1/X = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 2):

add `dtype=np.float32 (or float64)` to declare the type as float.

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train], dtype=np.float32 ).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
Y = np.array([i[1] for i in train], dtype=np.float32 )

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test], dtype=np.float32 ).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
test_y = np.array([i[1] for i in test], dtype=np.float32 )
```